# Asset won't render at all

Tags: rendering, instances, asset

I have a problem that occasionally occurs when rendering premade assets. Namely, I create some assets so I can speed up my work but at some point, some or all assets that have been added to the new project won't render at all (cycles and eevee).

I figured out that somehow, an object inside of my asset has changed the render state, and I cannot find out why this is happening. I can see them when I use *Make Instances Real* and "unpack" the assets.

I'm sending some screenshots and one example in link below.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoXovnN-smChgdseJ7VvoZHl5pfRCQ?e=nwvThs

I appreciate it if someone could solve this mystery for me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out what cause my asset desappear in render. Long time ago I have find very useful keyboard shortcut for, not just hiding/unhiding object from viewport, but disable the object from viewport and render in the same time.

For some reason, when I hide asset using this shortcut, and unhide after that, it stays disabled for render but visible in viewport.

There are the shortcuts below:

First you need to disable original Blender shortcuts
[image]

and afterwards add new one:
[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work very well with assets.

Comment: this doesn't really solve the issue as the linked file is not changed. Once you add a new sofa or recall the link, the hiddenness will return.

Comment: No, It doesn't...it just info what is the cause of hiddenness. Just wanted to share with you. I asked man who create the script for this shortcut to modify it so it can unhide the render visibility too...I'm waiting for the answer...

Comment: I asked guy who create the script for shortcut if he can update it...and he does! If somebody is intereseted for this shortcut:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159317/how-can-i-create-a-shortcut-that-will-hide-an-object-from-viewport-and-render/159327?noredirect=1#comment489059_159327

Answer (score 1):

As to the "Why", no one can tell other than the asset author. Either he was careless, did not notice the mistake or had other motives.

How to fix it without breaking you collection instance.

1. Create a new scene in your file front the *Scene* drop down in the header
2. Open a second *Outliner* editor
3. Change the outliner to *Orphaned Data* mode
4. There you should find your *Sofa* collection
5. Drag it from you *Orphaned Data* outliner to the current scene one.
6. There you can expand the asset and browse its content, changing visibility for the required objects.

All current instances of the *Sofa* collection should update automatically to reflect the changes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Duarte for your answer...wll, I'm the one who have create those assets (this sofa is just one example from my project)...and everything works fine until one moment when...well, it stops rendering :)

And i don't have a clue what I did to make that change :(

Just one question, what do I get following your process? I get the same results by using "Make instances real" function...in both way we unpack/broke my asset. I hope there is a way not to do that...just to change the state inside the asset... :(

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well if you created the asset, just go to the original file and fix it there before linking into your project file. If you already appended however, by following my process you edit the original collection (in a separate scene), rather than "exploding" one its instances. By doing so, not only you keep the instances, you fix the issue for all of them at once, not just the one you exploded. You can also go back to this scene and do any further edits there that propagate to all instances.

Comment: It is like that as you wrote in that file I've sent because it's file with imported asset, but in original file all objects are alredy set as visible in render :(.

Comment: Wierd, when I add the same asset beside one which won't render...it's been visible in render. I have replace all my assets in project which won't appear in render with the same one...and it works fine. I tried two...three times...works perfectly. And I just edit the walls  of appartment because I have noticed small mistake....and after that, again I lost all assets in render... :(

I'm pretty frustrated with this...